# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ']'

Tags: php, guzzle

Вот фрагмент кода:

```
$http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

$response = $http->post('https://anilist.co/api/v2/oauth/token', [
    "form_params" => [
        "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
        "client_id" => "1400",
        "client_secret" => "2fIcQ0M3iHgrh63B09oh8z521bnGpjkw3LxvAKeh",
        "redirect_uri" => "https://example.com/",
        "code" => $code
    ],
    "headers" => [
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json"
    ]
]);

return json_decode($response->getBody())->access_token;
```

Ошибка `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ']'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"headers" => [
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json"
]
```

Ошибка синтаксиса.

```
"headers" => [
    "Content-Type" => "application/json",
    "Accept" => "application/json"
]
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST https://anilist.co/api/v2/oauth/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"error":"unsupported_grant_type","message":"The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server." (truncated...) in C:\web\site\com\api\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php:113 Stack trace: #0

Comment: Это уже из другой оперы. Ковыряйте Guzzle и документацию по тому сервису, к которому цепляетесь. Описанную проблему - `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ']'` - решили, дальше - сами. :)

Comment: Просто в документации написано
`$http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

$response = $http->post('https://anilist.co/api/v2/oauth/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'client_id' => '{client_id}',
        'client_secret' => '{client_secret}',
        'redirect_uri' => '{redirect_uri}', // http://example.com/callback
        'code' => '{code}', // The Authorization code received previously
    ],
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
    ]
]);`

Comment: 1. Guzzle. "Я отправляю Вас к первоисточнику". http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#headers
2. `'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'` && `"error":"unsupported_grant_type"` => прямой путь в техподдержку сервиса anilist.co
3. Если в доке по сервису написано `'headers' => [ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json', ]`, то это уже говорит об уровне сервиса и/или качестве документации. Не забывайте про "на сарае написано х%й, а там - дрова!" Но я для чистоты эксперимента убедился бы, что в литерале 'authorization_code' все буквы - латинские. Удачи!